# cc (mail) after say 6th email

Tags: c#, format, mailaddress

I am trying to send multiple emails (>10) using Mailaddress class but apparently, it's not liking it. 
is there a way to attach emails after the 6th to CC?

or any other work around?

I have:

```
(<email1@test.com>; <email2@test.com>; <email3@test.com>, <email4@test.com>; <email5@test.com>; \r\n\t<email6@test.com>, <email7@test.com>; <email8@test.com>\r\n\TEXT)
```

I do Environment.NewLine,
I replace < , > , \t and " " with "" (don't know any other better way to format it)

when I try to send it via mailaddress class I am getting an format error.
but is working fine when the number of emails are less.

> **Solved:**
>
> ```
>             string to = "";
>             string cc = "";
>             int i = 0;
>             foreach (string item in multiAddress.Split(','))
>             {
>                 i += 1;
>                 if (i < 10)
>                 {
>                     to += item + ",";
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     cc += item + ",";
>                 }
>             }
>             to = to.Remove(to.Length - 1);
>             cc = cc.Remove(cc.Length - 1);
> ```

Comment: Why the tabs and line breaks?

Comment: Please add to your question the code used to send mail to this list of mail addresses

Comment: I am getting those emailddress es from another server. Thats the way its comes to my software.

Comment: Did you try to send the emails witout the '<>' and separated by commas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you use the regular way to send Email to multiple address? into a String, separeted by commas like this:

```
string recipients="email1@test.com,email2@test.com,email3@test.com" etc..
```

I personally got an error when I tried to send to more than 9 recipients, so I wrote the following code snippet that after the 9th recipient it automatically moves the recipients to the CC field.

```
       var emailAddresses= "YourEmailAddresses";

        //conccatenat all the email addresses into one variable
        //if there is more than 9 recipients it moves them to the CC field
        string to="";
        string cc = "";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string item in emailAddresses) {
            i += 1;
            if (i < 10) {
                to += item + ",";
            }
            else
            {
                cc += item + ",";
            }
         to = to.Remove(to.Length - 1);
```

If you use the loop make sure to remove the last comma on the string (because it adds a comma after each entry so you will have one extra after the last email).

Comment: How it be an answer to the question?

Comment: @un-lucky I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: I did, isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to isolate mail addresses from others characters
For example:

```
(<)(\w+@\w+\.\w+)(>)
```

Will match any mail address between angles.

```
        string source = "(<email1@test.com>; <email2@test.com>; <email3@test.com>, <email4@test.com>; <email5@test.com>; \r\n\t<email6@test.com>, <email7@test.com>; <email8@test.com>\r\nTEXT)";
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"(<)(\w+@\w+\.\w+)(>)");

        MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(source);
        foreach (Match match in matches) {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
```

Here you are a [running example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0zUicz).

Comment: what do you mean with `why new line?' (also, If you feel the answer is helpfull, please, upvote it)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a code to get the cc mail as follows with regular C# code using skip method

```
   public static string[] GetCCEmails()
   {
       const int limitToIncludeCC = 10 ;// no of email to be skipped
       string[] emailAdresses = new string[] { "emailadress1@xx.com", "emailadress2@xx.com", "emailadress2@xx.com", "emailadress3@xx.com", "emailadress4@xx.com", "emailadress5@xx.com" };
       var ccmailIDs = emailAdresses.Skip(limitToIncludeCC);
       return ccmailIDs.ToArray();
    }
```

and assign this array to CC property of MailMessage class of [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx).